# Does a simple Linearlayout recycle its child views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I read that components like Listview, Gridview, and Viewpager recycle the child views as they move off-screen [Reference](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

Is it also the case for Linearlayouts ?

Comment: No. A LinearLayout isn't a `Scrollable` View. So, it doesn't recycle its children.

Comment: Views don't recycle their child views. If you want to recycle child views, google for "ViewHolder". However, there's little reason to recycle views unless you have complicated child views or a lot of them.

Comment: @DerGol...lum what about a simple scrollview?

Comment: @WildThing. ScrollView doesn't do recycle either. You have to manually write your own if you want.

Comment: I'am a little bit confusing now....

Comment: @WildThing `ScrollView` holds only one child so it doesn't do any child views recycling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it also the case for Linearlayouts ?

No, because a `LinearLayout` does not change its child views, and so there is nothing for it to be recycling.

> what about a simple scrollview?

No, because a `ScrollView` does not change its child views, and so there is nothing for it to be recycling.

Comment: I have a lot of imagebuttons that i need to gather in the same view, what's the best option regarding memory management?

Comment: @WildThing: I do not know how many "a lot" is, or why you think that `ImageButton` is the proper widget. If you feel that you need to recycle `ImageButton` widgets, use a `RecyclerView`.